# Convert polyline to Bezier?

Tags: javascript, svg, polyline

I have a polyline, for example:

`<polyline xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke-linecap="round" points="5,-56.25 15,-37.5 25,-97.9167 35,-25 45,-37.5 55,0 65,-50 75,-100 85,-25 95,-87.5 105,-50 115,0" />`

shown as the blue graph below. I'd rather it be a curvy graph, like the orange path below:

[image: polyline graph]

Is there a library or something an svg graph-maker can use to do that?

Comment: Try d3js and associated modules like d3-interpolate.

Comment: Thank you. I keep seeing that name pop up so I guess it's probably something I'll have to learn sooner or later.